# highcharts, stacked column, switchrowsandcolumns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to be able to toggle between my groupings, (time/priority). I have a stacked column chart. there is a option to do this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/switchrowsandcolumns/). But it appears that it may only work with data already in a table, and I am bringing in my data as JSON.

my javascript is:

```
  var chart_ops_support_times = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_ops_support_times',
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ' '
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'one hour','2 hours','4 hours',
            '8 hours','one day','2 days',
            'one week','> one week'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'counts'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        floating: true,
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false,
        symbolHeight: 10,
        symbolWidth: 10

    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return "<b>" + this.x + "</b><br/>" +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + "<br/>" +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Data module won't work with JSON.

> The Data module provides options for loading data from external sources, like CSV files, HTML tables or Google Spreadsheets, in a convenient way, using a declarative options set. 
>   (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module)

Instead of using data module for this, you could parse your data from JSON to be used one way or another.

Other option is to create hidden HTML table with data from JSON and later use Highcharts with data module and use table.